# How to calculate duration when the clock resets?

Tags: mysql, datetime

What I want to do is simple
I have a df full of start_times & finish_times.
All start & finish in the same day except 2 rows
The time is in a 24 hr format

I want to calculate the min, max, & avg of the calculated time duration.
The problem is out of the 230 rows, 2 of the elapsed times reset.
e.g. One Start time is 2020-10-14 23:37:26 & its corresponding finish time is 2020-10-15 00:19:47
and I have another row where the exam starts 1 day & finishes the next

I stored the values as DATETIME
How do I go about converting this to my desired output?

```
SELECT AVG(SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, Start_Time, Finish_Time))) AS 
      Avg_Exam_Duration, 
      MIN(SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, Start_Time, Finish_Time))) AS 
      Min_Exam_Duration,
      MAX(SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, Start_Time, Finish_Time))) AS 
      Max_Exam_Duration,
      Room_ID FROM exam
      GROUP BY Room_ID;
```

Desired output would correctly calculate the Max, Min, & Avg of the duration (time elapsed) between time in minutes

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTyEn.png)

Comment: Please provide sample data, current and desired results. You do not describe how you want to handle the offending rows, so it is unclear which solution you are after.

Comment: Please show us some sample rows of data from your database. Please [edit] your question. Without seeing the actual values of some of your pairs of timestamps, we can only guess at your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
TIMEDIFF(Finish_Time, Start_Time)
```

use:

```
SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, Start_Time, Finish_Time))
```

(Note the changed order of parameters.)

Comment: I still receive negative time elapsed which is skewing my data for the min & max

Comment: give me an example start time and finish time and your updated sql?  ideally put create table & insert statements and your select into https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0 (with whatever version you actually have)  did you remember to put start time first?

Comment: @Pandda: given your description of the problem, this answer should do what you want. Else, you need  to provide sample data and desired results, as commented under your question already.